# Limit stereographic plot to a quarter or section in Basemap

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I've been searching on stackoverflow and all over the internet but just did not find a solution for my problem.

I want to reduce a stereographic plot to the area with actually valid points which ge plotted. That means "cutting away" the white excess on the image i attached. The documentation of Basemap did not really help.

Plot made with Basemap showing the region in blue I want it to reduce to:
[image]

The code i used to plot the figure reads:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm

field = np.ones(shape=(20,80))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

lonsize=[-50,30]
latsize=[60,80]
m = Basemap(width=4500000,height=3000000,
        resolution='i',projection='stere',boundinglat=45,
        lat_0=70,lon_0=-10.)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 91., 30.),labels=[1,1,1,1])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 180., 30.),labels=[1,1,0,1],size=10)
m.fillcontinents(color='grey',lake_color='grey')

lonnew = np.linspace(-50, 30, 80)
latnew = np.linspace(60, 80, 20)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lonnew, latnew)
xx, yy = m(lons, lats)
m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, field, cmap='Spectral_r')
plt.show()
```

This is a "real world" example of what I want to get:
[image]

I hope that someone knows a way to get this result with Basemap. Thank you!

Comment: One option may be to use `cartopy` instead of `basemap`. A possible solution would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463643/cartopy-albersequalarea-limit-region-using-lon-and-lat). But in that case it would be hard to get the ticks and ticklabels working (as this is at present not supported by cartopy).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, stopped trying to get it working in Basemap and also didn't need the plots after all. But will have a look into it when I have some spare time :)